# Is there a GitHub API to get autocomplete suggestions for user/organization name?

Tags: github, autocomplete, github-api

I know how to get the [list of organizations for a user](http://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/).

However, I want to let the user type in the user/organization name and provide autocomplete for that name where the autocomplete includes all user/organizations, not just the organizations they belong to.

It would be too long to get the entire list (and I am not sure that GitHub even exposes that), but the top 5-20 for any given prefix is all I want.

The Search API smells more like a single transaction search and not an autocomplete API, so while I could use it, most likely it would hit the rate limit too often and give a bad UX.

There is something close to this with [https://github.com/autocomplete/users?q=*prefix*](https://github.com/autocomplete/users?q=____), but that is not part of the official GitHub API, so I know that the back end does support these kind of queries... I am just not finding it from the API documentation, and I don't want to access a non-API URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub does not do this for you and likely never will. One option you have is to construct a service like that yourself and constantly update your list of users. One way to update the list of users (sanely) is to do the following:

- Make an initial `GET` to `/users?per_page=100`
- Save the `ETag` header that's returned and use pagination to get all of the most recent ones
- On future requests send along the `ETag` and when there are new users, save the newest `ETag`.
- Repeat.

So you'll be able to then build an auto-completion service yourself so long as you keep your listing of GitHub users up-to-date.

Also note, that sending along the `ETag` will save your ratelimit if there is nothing new to return.

Comment: They have this API: https://api.github.com/search/users?q=foo and 100 results (just the first page) is more than enough for the purpose of suggestions.

Comment: The search api is also available as endpoint in their graphql api, where you can specify what result values you want, if you just want the user names